# selenium web driver finding elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span>
<br/>
   For use to protect against or prevent actual or potential fraud, unauthorized transactions,claims or other liability.
</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</div>
<span align="center">     Selection of this option will automatically log you out of the system.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I have same button class name for both the buttons . How to find the first button and click it . The only difference in those is span text which i tried but it is not working out .

```
List<WebElement> buttons=driver.findElements(By.className("ui-dialobuttonset"));
buttons.get(0).click().
```

dint work

Comment: It's difficult to get the reason when the html source is not available. Please     post the section of source. Otherwise, I can only suggest you try something `By.xpath` since `By.className` does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class called **ui-state-hover** in first button which is not present in button 2. So You can try this xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'ui-state-hover')]")).click();
```

Comment: Tried this way , but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The className your finding is of div, to find list of buttons give className of button i.e. ui-button or you can find buttons by tagName

`List<WebElement> buttons=driver.findElements(By.className("ui-button"));
buttons.get(0).click();`

Comment: Did not work . I was able to find it out using xpath driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/button[1]")).click(); but i dont feel so this is the best approach looking for an element starting  from the Html tag

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code to click on the first button directly..

Make sure to use the correct class name "Class name is wrong in the code you written above"

`wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[1]"))`

if it doesnot work try below code

```
List<WebElement> buttons=wd.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']")); 
buttons.get(0).click();
```